# dlib face detection error : Unsupported image type, must be 8bit gray or RGB image

Tags: python, image, numpy, face-detection, dlib

i am trying to crop out the faces from instagram avatars by first detecting the faces and then resizing the image. i am reading all the images which have been stored in a dataframe and then creating a numpy array. Then i am running a frontal face detector which returns me an object but when i call the object it returns me the error stated. i tried giving only colored images as input but that did not work neither did try and except. Here is the code:

```
 df = pd.read_csv('/home/instaurls2.csv')
img_width, img_height = 139, 139
confidence = 0.8
#graph = K.get_session().graph
data1 = np.array([io.imread(row[1]) for row in df.itertuples()])
#print(data1)
detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
print (detector)
dets=detector(data1,1) # **error arrives here**
print (dets)
output=None
for i, d in enumerate(dets):
    data1 = data1[d.top():d.bottom(), d.left():d.right()]
    data1 = resize(data1, (img_width, img_height))
    output = np.expand_dims(data1, axis=0)
print (output)
```

Comment: I suspect it's the format of your data1 array. Is it floats or strings when it should be ints or bytes?

Comment: @Pam [[[[ 34  34  34]
   [ 35  35  35]
   [ 40  40  40]
   ...
   [  8   8   8]
   [ 12  12  12]
   [ 12  12  12]]

  [[ 39  39  39]
   [ 30  30  30]
   [ 25  25  25]
   ...
   [ 11  11  11]
   [  1   1   1]
   [  5   5   5]]

  [[ 54  54  54]
   [ 44  44  44]
   [ 34  34  34]
   ...
   [ 32  32  32]
   [  9   9   9]
   [  0   0   0]]

  ... 
that's how my data1 looks like i guess it's int and not string or float

Comment: I think that might be one too many square braces []. Three channels, R, G, and B; one height; one width makes three sets of square braces.

Comment: Also, you have it in "packed" form there (rgb, rgb, rgb....). I don't know if dlib expects planar (rrrr...., gggg...., bbbb....) or not. Might not be a problem, though.

Comment: @Pam what could be the error and how can i rectify it/

Comment: reshape data1 so that it's (channels, height, width), then display it. That should get rid of your square brackets and might fix your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Opencv reads image as BGR per default.

You can read images with cv2:

```
import cv2
cv2.imread(image_filepath)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
image.astype('uint8')
```